# Is there a way to be able to hold HoverTool information by clicking in Bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, hover, bokeh

I am working on a project where lines are made between circles, right now the user can see the lines between circles by hovering over a circle. For ease of use I would like the user to be able to see the lines when hovering over a circle but also when clicking on a circle and then moving away from it. Then when the user clicks on an empty space the lines disappear again.

My code is mostly based on the following code from the [Bokeh documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-hover-tool):

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("hover_callback.html")

# define some points and a little graph between them
x = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7]
y = [6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5]
links = {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [0, 3, 4],
    2: [0, 5],
    3: [1, 4],
    4: [1, 3],
    5: [2, 3, 4]
}

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="", toolbar_location=None, title='Hover over points')

source = ColumnDataSource({'x0': [], 'y0': [], 'x1': [], 'y1': []})
sr = p.segment(x0='x0', y0='y0', x1='x1', y1='y1', color='olive', alpha=0.6, line_width=3, source=source, )
cr = p.circle(x, y, color='olive', size=30, alpha=0.4, hover_color='olive', hover_alpha=1.0)

# add a hover tool that sets the link data for a hovered circle
code = """
const links = %s
const data = {'x0': [], 'y0': [], 'x1': [], 'y1': []}
const indices = cb_data.index.indices
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    const start = indices[i]
    for (var j = 0; j < links[start].length; j++) {
        const end = links[start][j]
        data['x0'].push(circle.data.x[start])
        data['y0'].push(circle.data.y[start])
        data['x1'].push(circle.data.x[end])
        data['y1'].push(circle.data.y[end])
    }
}
segment.data = data
""" % links

callback = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr.data_source, 'segment': sr.data_source}, code=code)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback, renderers=[cr]))

show(p)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the data in a complicated way, I would instead suggest just adding the `segment` renderer once, and then add a `TapTool` with a callback that just toggles the segment visibility:

```py
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(sr=sr)}, code="""
sr.visible = !sr.visible
""")
```